# Telerik-mvc menu: align an individual element to the right?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, menu, telerik-mvc

In an asp.net-mvc-3 project, I'm going to be using Telerik Extensions.

Right now, I'm looking at their Menu ( http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/menu ), and **wondering if one could align the last item to the far right of the bar**, but leaving the rest stacked to the right.

The documentation of Menu explains how to reverse the alignment of the whole Menu, but neither it nor the MenuItem show any obvious way to control their layout.

Is this possible?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a CssClass to the last menu item and style it to to the right.

Check the .HtmlAttributes object of the menu item api.

```
ci.Add().Text("Categories")
  .Url(Url.Action("Categories", "ProductCategories"))
  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class="last"});
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution did exactly what I needed.
I ended up using this:
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "float:right;" })
which does the same thing without needing to define the class elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for supplying your answer.  It was what I was looking for exactly, too.